# Scheme Problem: car: contract violation expected: pair? given: '()

Tags: scheme, racket

I am stuck with this particular problem I was doing for fun:
Why does it cause a contract violation everytime car comes around? And are there any possible fixes?

```
(define (fv expr)
  (cond ((eq? (car expr) 'lambda) (fv (cadr (cdr expr))))
        ((pair? (car expr)) (union (fv (car expr)) (fv (cdr expr))))
        ((symbol? (car expr)) (remove (car expr) (fv (cdr expr))))
        (else '())))

(define (union set1 set2)
  (cond ((null? set1) set2)
        ((member (car set1) set2) (union (cdr set1) set2))
        (else (cons (car set1) (union (cdr set1) set2)))))

(define (remove item set)
  (cond ((null? set) '())
        ((equal? item (car set)) (cdr set))
        (else (cons (car set) (remove item (cdr set))))))
```

Input = `(fv '(λ f (λ x (f ((t g) g)))))`

Output =

> car: contract violation expected: pair?  given: '()

Output Should Be: `(t g)`

Comment: It's not happening every time car comes around. The recursion is eventually calling `car` on an empty list, which gets an error.

Comment: It would help if you explained what this is supposed to do.

Comment: There are lots of calls to `car`. Does the debugger show the stack trace so you can see where the error happened?

Comment: Think about what happens in `(fv '())`. (One of your procedures does not have the same structure as the others. This is suspicious.)

Comment: Looking at your input and because `(eq? 'λ 'lambda) ; ==> #f` one of the second and third cond term will hit since a pair can either have a list or a symbol. These then recurse with `(cdr expr)` so eventually you get to `(fv '())`. You need that case to not do any `car`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

```
 car: contract violation expected: pair? given: '()
```

means that the function `car` was called with the argument `'()` (the empty list) and this gives an error.

Now you know that the problem is related to a call to `car`.
Since `car` is called multiple times in your program it is hard
to spot which `car` is the culprit. Presumably your Scheme implementation
displays a source locations that points to the offending expression.

But let's say you are not so lucky. In that case, you'll need to figure out which function has the problem. Inserting a few calls to `display` helps:

```
(define (fv expr)
  (display (list 'fv: 'expr expr) (newline)
  (cond ((eq? (car expr) 'lambda) (fv (cadr (cdr expr))))
        ((pair? (car expr)) (union (fv (car expr)) (fv (cdr expr))))
        ((symbol? (car expr)) (remove (car expr) (fv (cdr expr))))
        (else '())))

(define (union set1 set2)
  (display (list 'union: 'set1 set1 'set2 set2) (newline)
  (cond ((null? set1) set2)
        ((member (car set1) set2) (union (cdr set1) set2))
        (else (cons (car set1) (union (cdr set1) set2)))))

(define (remove item set)
  (display (list 'remove: 'item item 'set set) (newline)
  (cond ((null? set) '())
        ((equal? item (car set)) (cdr set))
        (else (cons (car set) (remove item (cdr set))))))
```

If you try your example now, you'll see which function is called before the error occurs. In this case, I bet the problem is `fv`. Here `car` is called without a check that the argument is a non-empty list first.